# Proving those hard cyclic inequalities

Tags: reference-request, inequality, book-recommendation

From time to time some user asks for help to prove a cyclic inequality, that is, something like
$$f(x,y,z)\le k$$
where $x,y,z$ are usually real positive numbers and $f$ is a 'cyclic function' (I don't know the standard name for this), that is, it is a function that satisfies
$$f(x,y,z)=f(z,x,y)$$
There is sometimes an additional condition of the from $g(x,y,z)=r$ where $g$ is also a cyclic function.

[Example 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/980451/beautiful-cyclic-inequality), [example 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/912905/prove-fracab1c2-fracbc1a2-fracca1b2-le-frac34-if-a2) (there are many more).

I have tried many of them, but I feel useless (I seldom manage to prove them, only the easiest ones), and, from the answers to these questions, I see that there is no 'magic' theorem or technique.

*My question*: is there any book with selected exercises, from easy to hard, to get trained in this kind of problems?

Comment: I know only [Muirhead's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muirhead%27s_inequality) about cyclic inequalities

Comment: There are some useful references given [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/919688/books-for-inequality-proofs?rq=1), but more for inequalities in general.

Comment: Pham Kim Hung - Secrets in Inequalities (volume 1 and 2)  are nice books!